# DateFormat giving incorrect value

Tags: java

I wanted to convert `String` to `Date`. My code:

```
    String maturityDate = "20150722";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd");
    Date date = formatter.parse(maturityDate);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Expected Result :

```
Input 20150722
Output Wed Jul 22 00:07:00 IST 2015
```

Actual Result :

```
Input 20150722
Output Thu Jan 22 00:07:00 IST 2015
```

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *What could be the cause?*

Cause is `m` letter means minute in `SimpleDateFormat` pattern. You mean `M` for months.

**SOLUTION**
Change your format from `yyyymmdd` to `yyyyMMdd`.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
```

In the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you will find the complete list:

```
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
m   Minute in hour  Number  30
```